# Order of dihedral groups depends on the ambient space?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, symmetry

$D_{2n}$ usually denotes the set of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon, where by "symmetry" we mean a movement of the $n$-gon in 3-space that gets us back to occupying the original position. However, I'm curious why we define it to be in 3-space. Obviously, from a practical point of view, this has a physical/geometric interpretation, but I'm wondering if that's the main reason why we define it that way.

For example, if we restrict our space to 2-space, then we cannot "flip the $n$-gon over", so the set of symmetries doesn't include reflections; only rotations. Then the order of the group is only $n$, not $2n$. And if we are considering, say, the symmetries of 3D objects, is our space still restricted to 3-space? Or would it make any sense to speak of moving the 3D object around in 4-space (or higher), just like we did with our 2D $n$-gons in 3-space? Are these considerations even useful? Do we care about spaces other than 3-space (or 2-space)?

Comment: An operation in 2-space is a subset of 3-space.  That is why.

Comment: I think you're confusing two things. First, yes the set of symmetries of an object depends in some sense in what exactly we mean by symmetries.

Comment: But second, no, the order of the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ does not vary. The dihedral group $D_{2n}$ can be defined in many different ways, for example, as the symmetries of a cycle graph of order $n$, the isometries of a regular $n$-gon (and in fact, if you define it this, way, you don't have to worry if you're in $2$-space or $3$-space). It can also be defined directly as a permutation group, generated by two specific permutations, etc.

Comment: For example, somebody working in (abstract) group theory might simply say a dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is any group generated by two involutions such that the product of the involutions has order $n$, without reference to any symmetries at all.

Comment: Now, if you have a regular $n$-gon, and your definition of symmetry only includes rotations but not reflections (say you only consider orientation preserving symmetries), then the group you get is smaller, but it is not the dihedral group.

Comment: I consider the diheral group to be the set of isometries of a regular polygon. The ability to rotate and reflect aren't required but do make for a useful geometric interpretation of how the group acts on the polygon. 

Also, studying how a group acts on a linear space is called representation theory and you can consider spaces of arbitrary dimension with some fixed subspace within that context. Reflections are simple linear transformations as well so there is no need to move up from two to three dimensions to perform them.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dihedral group is a fixed group that does not change based on context, except given the order. If you restrict the symmetries of the regular polygon that are allowed, you will obtain a subgroup of the dihedral group, as the dihedral group is the group of all possible symmetries of the regular polygon.

I've never heard of defining the dihedral group as being a group of symmetries in $3$-space, and it's not necessary to extend to $3$-space unless you are only allowing rotations. Reflections are also symmetries of the polygon, and if you combine the rotations and the reflections in $2$-space you get the complete dihedral group. In any case, the dihedral group is *intrinsic*, meaning you can define it without reference to any ambient space. Namely, if you consider the $n$-gon as a metric space in its own right, the dihedral group is the group of isometries of this metric space.

Comment: Ok, thanks. For reference, if anyone cares, my understanding of the definition as being in 3-space comes from Dummit & Foote's *Abstract Algebra*, p.23, in the section on Dihedral Groups.

Comment: @twosigma I guess they're only allowing orientation-preserving symmetries then. That's equivalent to allowing reflections in $2$-space anyway, so we're all talking about the same group at least.